# What ABI, if any, restricts the size of [u]intmax_t?

Tags: c, c99, c11, abi

Starting with the 1999 edition, the ISO C standard defines a standard header `<stdint.h>` which defines, among other things, the typedefs `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`. These designate, respectively, "a (signed|unsigned) integer type capable of representing any value of any (signed|unsigned) integer type".

For example, if, as is typical, the widest signed and unsigned integer types are `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`, both of which are typically 64 bits, then `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` might be defined in `<stdint.h>` as follows:

```
typedef long long int intmax_t;
typedef unsigned long long int uintmax_t;
```

There is a limited set of predefined signed and unsigned integer types, ranging from `signed`, `unsigned`, and plain `char` up to `signed` and `unsigned` `long long int`.

C99 and C11 also permit implementations to define *extended integer types*, which are distinct from any of the standard types and have names that are implementation-defined keywords.

Both gcc and clang, on some but not all targets, support types `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`. These act like 128-bit integer types, but they are *not* treated as *extended integer types*, and the documentation for both compilers states that they do not support any extended integer types. Because these are not *integer types* as the Standard defines the term, the typedefs `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are for 64-bit types, not 128-bit types.

None of this violates the C standard (implementations are not required to have any extended integer types, and they're permitted to have arbitrary extensions as long as they don't break any strictly conforming programs). But it seems to me that it would make perfect sense for `__int128` and `unsigned __int128` to be treated as extended integer types, and for `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` to be 128-bit types.

The rationale for *not* doing this is that changing the size of `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` would be "an ABI-incompatible change".

The [Clang C++ status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) says, in footnote (5):

> No compiler changes are required for an implementation such as Clang that does not provide any extended integer types. `__int128` is not treated as an extended integer type, because changing `intmax_t` would be an ABI-incompatible change.

(Yes, this primarily discusses C++, but the rules are the same as for C.)

In a [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49595), the claim is made that:

> `sizeof(intmax_t)` is fixed by various LP64 ABIs and cannot be changed

In both cases, no reference is given for this claim.

An [x86_64 ABI document](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) titled "System V Application Binary Interface, AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement, Draft Version 0.99.6" does not mention `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`, or even the `<stdint.h>` header. It does specify sizes and alignments for the predefined integer types (in Figure 3.1).

Finally, my question: Is the claim that the sizes of `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` restricted by an ABI valid? If so, what ABI imposes such a requirement? (And, incidentally, why?)

(In my opinion, such a requirement, if it exists, is unwise. It defeats the purpose of the C standard's permission to define extended integer types, and the intended meaning of `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`. It makes it much more difficult to use 128-bit integer types effectively on systems that support them, while falling back to narrower types on other systems.)

**Update**: In N2303, titled "intmax t, a way out", Jens Gustedt proposes tweaking the definitions of `[u]intmax_t` to permit adding extended integer types wider than `long long` without having to update `[u]intmax_t`. For example, `intmax_t` might be a typedef for `long long`, but the implementation could still provide, say, `__int128` as an *extended integer type*.

References:

- [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), a draft of the C99 standard
- [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), a draft of the C11 standard
- [N2303](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2303.pdf), a proposal by Jens Gustedt
- [System V AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

Comment: There's an argument to be made that 64bits is enough for most uses.  Having `intmax_t` be an extended precision type that requires carry/borrow for add/sub, and even more complexity for mul/div, would lead to more bloated code than necessary.  Basically I'm saying that some programmers may assume `intmax_t` to be no wider than the target can efficiently support.  This is **not a good argument**, since `intmax_t` is 64bit on most 32bit machines.  It would be nice if there was an `int128_t`, but `intmax_t` can't change on existing platforms without breaking backwards compat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Colonel Thirty Two notes, a compiler unilaterally making this change would break calls between compilation units that pass `uintmax_t` parameters or return `uintmax_t` values.  Even though the SysV ABI doesn't define how these types are passed, as a matter of practicality maintaining their definitions is part of conforming to the platform ABI.

Even if it weren't for this ABI issue, a compiler still couldn't unilaterally make this change, because it would require matching changes to every targeted platform's C standard library.  Specifically, it would at least require updates to the `printf` and `scanf` function family, `imaxabs`, `imaxdiv`, and `strtoimax` and `strtoumax` and their variants.

Comment: You forgot to mention the preprocessor, that also is supposed to work with `[u]intmax_t`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I definitely didn't intend my list of affected components to be exhaustive =)

Answer (score 8):

Changing types like `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` also changes the ABI of all the programs that use them, as they now refer to different types.

Say you have program A that uses a function in shared library B with a `uintmax_t` parameter. If GCC changes the definition of `uintmax_t` and A (but not B) gets recompiled, then `uintmax_t` in A and `uintmax_t` in B now refer to two different types, breaking the ABI.

Comment: It's too bad C never defined a standard way via which prototypes could specify types in absolute terms.  How many zillions of dollars would have been saved if the prototype for `printf` could have specified "convert all integer values to N bits, all floating-point values to M bits, and all pointers to `void*`"?  On a system where the largest integer `printf` supported was 64 bits, code wanting to print the result of adding 123456 to an `int` wouldn't have to worry about whether the result would be an `int` or `long`, or the sizes of those types, since both would be passed as 64 bits.

Comment: If the `printf` function is limited to 64 bits, then even if `intmax_t` happens to be bigger, the best that could happen when trying to print an `intmax_t` would be for it to get converted to a 64-bit value and given to `printf`; that would allow values that fit in 64 bits to prints correctly, regardless of the type of `intmax_t`.

Comment: @supercat You do realize that C specifies fixed-sized types in `stdint.h`, and that vararg functions take more than just integers so that truncating only integers would add a weird corner-case?

Comment: The `stdint.h` types interact in implementation-dependent ways with other types, both with regard to promotion and the strict aliasing rules.  I mentioned `printf` because that's where problems are most obvious.  On most systems where `int` and `long` are both 32-bits, printing an `int32_t` may require either `%d` or `%ld`; one will be right and other other will invoke Undefined Behavior.  Some such systems require one, and some require the other, but I wouldn't be surprised if at least 10% of extant code for such systems uses the wrong one and only works because implementations are "nice".

Comment: I used integers for my example because `maxint_t` was being discussed; the problem is much more severe with floating-point types.  I suspect that 90% of code which uses `printf` with type `long double` invokes Undefined Behavior, and the fact that such code only works on systems which pass `long double` and `double` identically has led many compilers to define `long double` as 64 bits even when they use 80-bit types for calculations [using extended-precision for calculations is a good thing from both a semantic and efficiency standpoint *if and only if* it's available as a data type].

Answer (score 5):

I think the key to understand here is that just because something is not documented in an ABI specification does not mean it is not part of an ABI. As soon as a type is used across a library boundry then it's properties become part of the ABI of that library.

By defining (u)intmax_t in a standard header and using them in functions of the standard library they become part of the ABI of that library whether they are included in any formal ABI specification or not.

This is especially an issue for Unix-like platforms where the C standard library is treated as part of the platform, not part of the compiler.

Now it would be possible to transition this. Printf uses macros for type specifiers, so those macros could be defined differently depending on the size of intmax_t. Macros could similarly be used to map the handful of functions in the standard library to different implementations but it's a bunch of extra work for questionable gains, so it's hardly surprising that gcc took the path of least resistance to adding the functionality they needed.