# Assigning 128-bit integer in C

Tags: c, gcc, literals, 128-bit

When I try to assign an 128-bit integer in gcc 4.9.1, I get a `warning: integer constant is too large for its type`.

### Example Code

```
int main(void) {
  __uint128_t p = 47942806932686753431;

  return 0;
}
```

### Output

I'm compiling with `gcc -std=c11 -o test test.c` and I get:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:2:19: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
   __uint128_t p = 47942806932686753431;
               ^
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in gcc?

Comment: Also see ["Why isn't there int128_t?" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29638843/2410359).

Comment: `((__uint128_t)47942806*1000000+932686)*1000000+753431`

Comment: BTW, you should probably replace instances of `__uint128_t` with `unsigned __int128`. The former appears to be 'deprecated'.

Comment: _"When I try to assign an 128 bit integer"_ Whoops, nope, that's not what you're doing. You're trying to assign _to_ an 128 bit integer, but the thing you're assigning to it is not one!

Comment: There are 128 bit integers now? Right. 128-bit. Exponential growth. Is this to do with encryption?!

Comment: @SteveWoods it has nothing to do with encryption which is typically 256, 512, 1024-bit or longer. 128-bit integer support in gcc has been there since at least 2006

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in gcc?

The problem is in `47942806932686753431` part, not in `__uint128_t p`. According to [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) there's no way to declare 128 bit constant:

> There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide.

So, it seems that while you can have 128 bit *variables*, you cannot have 128 bit *constants*, unless your `long long` is 128 bit wide.

The workaround could be to construct 128 bit value from "narrower" integral constants using basic arithmetic operations, and hope for compiler to perform [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Comment: Maybe "cannot have 128 bit integer constants, unless your `intmax_t` is at least 128 bit wide"?

Comment: I'm not sure. The quoted docs mention "long long integer" type specifically.

Comment: In reader the C11 draft spec, it is clear that _integer constants_ must have at least the range of `long long/unsigned long long`.  It is not clear if _integer constants_ must have at least the range of `intmax_t/uintmax_t`.  I would _think_ it would be required.

Comment: @chux, these types are extensions and not covered by the standard. For the `intmax_t` types the standard provides the corresponding macros `INTMAX_C` that are guaranteed to create constants of the correct type.

Comment: @el.pescado, while there is no direct support, you still can have constant expressions of that type. E.g `((__int128_t)1000000000000*HIGH)+LOW` could be a way of constructing such an expression for a large value, where `HIGH` and `LOW` are the higher and lower digits of the number.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Macro `INTMAX_C(value)` requires `value` to be  an _unsuffixed integer constant_.  So it does not make a _integer constant_ out of something that was not all ready an _integer constant_.  `INTMAX_C()` does provide a type conversion.  So _if_ _integer constants_ are limited to the range of `long long`, `INTMAX_C()` will not help create a constant of the range of `intmax_t`.

Comment: @chux, this refers to 6.4.4.1 and says "integer constant" and not constant of some integer type. So it refers to the lexical definition that is given there. The only constraint that standard imposes on `[U]INTMAX_C` is that the value (!) must not exceed what is representable in the target type.

Comment: @Jens Gusted Agree and thank-you.  Minor correction that an additional constraint exist §7.20.4 2 imposes value "... shall be an unsuffixed integer constant". So it can be "123", but not "123LL".

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried this?

```
__int128 p = *(__int128*) "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f";
```

**EDIT Nov. 25**

Sorry for the poor clarification on previous post. Seriously, I didn't post this answer as a joke. Though the GCC doc states there's no way to express a 128-bit integer constant, this post simply provides a *workaround* for those who wants to assign values to __uint128_t variables with ease.

You may try to compile the code below with GCC (7.2.0) or Clang (5.0.0). It prints desired results.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    __uint128_t p = *(__int128*) "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f";
    printf("HIGH %016llx\n", (uint64_t) (p >> 64));
    printf("LOW  %016llx\n", (uint64_t) p);
    return 0;
}
```

The stdout:

```
HIGH 0f0e0d0c0b0a0908
LOW  0706050403020100
```

This is only regarded as a *workaround* since it plays tricks on pointers by placing the "value" in .rodata section (if you objdump it), and it's not portable (x86_64 and aarch64 are fine but not arm and x86). I think it's been enough for those coding on desktop machines.

Comment: Is this intended to be a joke?

Comment: Even assuming the string value is correct for whatever endianness is needed, that will likely result in a `SIGBUS` for any architecture that has alignment restrictions on `__int128` variables.

Comment: I found it actually works for gcc 5.2.0 on x86_64. Even with `int n = *(int*) "1234";`.
Maybe Andrew is right. The string constant is not guaranteed to be aligned and thus this trick may not work on archs other than x86.

Comment: @jerry73204 : in my case, the compiler is complaining in `C99` about the pointer with `error: expression must have a constant value
  __int128 llong_min=(*((char *){"\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfd"}));
                     ^`

Comment: Apart from alignment, the solution in this answer also has problems with strict aliasing, but something like `__uint128_t q = (union { unsigned char r[16]; __uint128_t i; }) 
    {00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,8,9,0xa,0xb,0xc,0xd,0xe,0xf}.i;` works. It assumes the endianness and the width of `char` as 8 bits, but so does the answer above this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a simple macro to combine two 64-bit values:

```
#define UINT128(hi, lo) (((__uint128_t) (hi)) << 64 | (lo))
```

Example usage:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UINT128(hi, lo) (((__uint128_t) (hi)) << 64 | (lo))

int main() {
  // Creates constant 0x010203040506070890a0b0c0d0e0f10
  __uint128_t x = UINT128(0x0102030405060708, 0x090a0b0c0d0e0f10);

  // Prints 1, 2, 3, 4, .. 15, 16
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", (int)((x >> (120 - 8*i)) & 255));
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Alternatively, you could move the 0x prefix into the macro (**not recommended**):

```
#define UINT128(hi, lo) (((__uint128_t) (0x##hi)) << 64 | (0x##lo))
```

So you can do `UINT128(0102030405060708, 090a0b0c0d0e0f10)` which is slightly shorter, but that might mess up syntax highlighting, because `0102030405060708` could be misinterpreted as an octal constant, and `090a0b0c0d0e0f10` is not a valid token by itself, which is why I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and cooked up a solution using user-defined literals.
Here is how you instantiate the user-defined literal `_xxl`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    auto a = 0xF0000000000000000000000000000000LLU;
    auto b = 0xF0000000000000000000000000000000_xxl;
    
    printf("sizeof(a): %zu\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("sizeof(b): %zu\n", sizeof(b));

    printf("a == 0? %s\n", a==0 ? "true":"false");
    printf("b == 0? %s\n", b==0 ? "true":"false");

    printf("b >> 124 = %x\n", b >> 124);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```cpp
sizeof(a): 8
sizeof(b): 16
a == 0? true
b == 0? false
b >> 124 = f
```

Here is the implementation for the user-defined literal `_xxl`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__
    using uint_xxl_t = __uint128_t;
    using sint_xxl_t = __int128_t;
    
namespace detail_xxl
{
    constexpr uint8_t hexval(char c) 
    { return c>='a' ? (10+c-'a') : c>='A' ? (10+c-'A') : c-'0'; }

    template <int BASE, uint_xxl_t V>
    constexpr uint_xxl_t lit_eval() { return V; }
    
    template <int BASE, uint_xxl_t V, char C, char... Cs>
    constexpr uint_xxl_t lit_eval() {
        static_assert( BASE!=16 || sizeof...(Cs) <=  32-1, "Literal too large for BASE=16");
        static_assert( BASE!=10 || sizeof...(Cs) <=  39-1, "Literal too large for BASE=10");
        static_assert( BASE!=8  || sizeof...(Cs) <=  44-1, "Literal too large for BASE=8");
        static_assert( BASE!=2  || sizeof...(Cs) <= 128-1, "Literal too large for BASE=2");
        return lit_eval<BASE, BASE*V + hexval(C), Cs...>();
    }
    
    template<char... Cs > struct LitEval 
    {static constexpr uint_xxl_t eval() {return lit_eval<10,0,Cs...>();} };

    template<char... Cs> struct LitEval<'0','x',Cs...> 
    {static constexpr uint_xxl_t eval() {return lit_eval<16,0,Cs...>();} };

    template<char... Cs> struct LitEval<'0','b',Cs...> 
    {static constexpr uint_xxl_t eval() {return lit_eval<2,0,Cs...>();} };

    template<char... Cs> struct LitEval<'0',Cs...> 
    {static constexpr uint_xxl_t eval() {return lit_eval<8,0,Cs...>();} };
    
    template<char... Cs> 
    constexpr uint_xxl_t operator "" _xxl() {return LitEval<Cs...>::eval();}
}

template<char... Cs> 
constexpr uint_xxl_t operator "" _xxl() {return ::detail_xxl::operator "" _xxl<Cs...>();}
    
#endif // __SIZEOF_INT128__
```

It can be used in `constexpr` just like normal integer constants:

```cpp
static_assert(   0_xxl == 0, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 0b0_xxl == 0, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(  00_xxl == 0, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 0x0_xxl == 0, "_xxl error" );

static_assert(   1_xxl == 1, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 0b1_xxl == 1, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(  01_xxl == 1, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 0x1_xxl == 1, "_xxl error" );

static_assert(      2_xxl == 2, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(   0b10_xxl == 2, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(     02_xxl == 2, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(    0x2_xxl == 2, "_xxl error" );

static_assert(      9_xxl == 9, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 0b1001_xxl == 9, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(    011_xxl == 9, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(    0x9_xxl == 9, "_xxl error" );

static_assert(     10_xxl == 10, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(    0xa_xxl == 10, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(    0xA_xxl == 10, "_xxl error" );

static_assert( 0xABCDEF_xxl == 0xABCDEF, "_xxl error" );
static_assert( 1122334455667788_xxl == 1122334455667788LLu, "_xxl error" );
static_assert(0x80000000000000000000000000000000_xxl >> 126 == 0b10, "_xxl error");
static_assert(0x80000000000000000000000000000000_xxl >> 127 == 0b01, "_xxl error");
static_assert( 0xF000000000000000B000000000000000_xxl > 0xB000000000000000, "_xxl error" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for your time, but your code is C++, not C.

Comment: ups... I didn't notice that

Comment: Still, nice answer