# Suffix for a intmax_t literal

Tags: c, literals

There doesn't seem to be a 'J' suffix (a la printf's %jd).

So, is it guaranteed that the `LL` and `ULL` suffixes are going to work with intmax_t and uintmax_t types?

```
#include <stdint.h>

intmax_t yuuge = 123456789101112131411516LL;
```

or is it possible that there are literals that are too big for the `LL` suffix?  Say, a (hypothetical) system with 32 bit int, 32 bit long, 64 bit long long, 128 bit intmax_t.

Comment: Detail: In C `123` is specified as a _constant_, not a _literal_.  C has 2 literals: _string literal_ and _compound literal_.  Both can have their address taken.  Code cannot take the address of  `123`.  Other languages do allow that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it possible that there are literals that are too big for the LL suffix

Yes, if the integer constant exceeds the range of `(u)intmax_t`, it is too big, with or without the `LL`.

See [Assigning 128 bit integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31461318/2410359)
 for a similar problem.

---

`LL` and `LLU` are not for types.  They are for integer constants.

An `L` or `LL` insures the *minimum* type of a constant.  The is no suffix for `intmax_t`.

```
123 is an `int`
123L is a `long`
123LL is a `long long`
123456789012345 is a `long long` on OP's hypothetical system even without LL
```

---

`intmax_t` may have the same range as `long long` - or it may be wider.  Both `intmax_t` and `long long` are at least 64-bit.

With a well warning enabled compiler, should the constant exceed the `intmax_t` range, a warning would occur.  Examples:

```
//  warning: integer overflow in expression
intmax_t yuuge1 = (intmax_t)123456*1000000000000000000 + 789101112131411516;

//  warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
intmax_t yuuge2 = 123456789101112131411516;
```

---

C provides macros for greatest-width integer constants

> The following macro expands to an integer constant expression having the value specified by its argument and the type intmax_t:  C11 §7.20.4.2 1
>
> ```
> INTMAX_C(value)
> ```

---

The `INTMAX_C(value)` does have a limitation

> The argument in any instance of these macros shall be an unsuffixed integer constant ... with a value that does not exceed the limits for the corresponding type.

The following   does not meet that requirement on machines with with 64-bit `intmax_t`.

```
// Not so portable code
intmax_t yuuge = INTMAX_C(123456789101112131411516);
```

`#` pre-processing is also limited to `intmax_t`.

Code that attempts to create a constant outside the `(u)int64_t` range can easily have portability problems.  For portability, another coding approach is advised (Avoid such large constants).

---

Answer (score 5):

**No suffix is needed** if you just want the value to be faithfully represented. The C language automatically gives integer literals the right type. Suffixes are only needed if you want to force a literal to have higher-rank type than it would naturally have due to its value (e.g. `1UL` to get the value 1 as `unsigned long` rather than `int`, or `-1UL` as an alternate expression for `ULONG_MAX`).

If you do want to force a literal to have type `intmax_t`, use the `INTMAX_C()` macro from `stdint.h`.