# Explain Big int in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to hold a value of range 10^20 in **C**. Heard that the big int in **C** can hold such big values. How to declare and use the big int in **C**.

Does anybody know of an easy way to do that? Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Well, `10 ^ 20` *does* fit into an ordinary `int` in C.

Comment: 10^20 is about 2^65, so 128 bit int can handle it, See if `int128_t` is available on your compiler.

Comment: @user3528438: What? `10^20 == 30`. If `INT_MAX < 30`, your implementation is nonconforming.

Comment: @EOF "^" is not"`^`".

Comment: @user3528438 how to use int128_t

Comment: Whether `__int128` is available or not depends on your system. What environment do you program for?  If it is available, it is just an ordinary type, like `int` or `long int`.

Comment: if `int128_t` is supported, then it should be in `stdint.h`. however according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638723/why-isnt-there-int128-t there's a high chance that the compiler may provide `__int128` but not `int126_t` so try both. To use `__int128` you don't need to include anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type `unsigned long long`, the range is at least `0..18446744073709551615`, but that's only 1.8E19, so slightly less than what you need. If you really want to go beyond 64 bits, you can check if your system supports 128 bit integers (as type `__int128`, `__int128_t`, `int128_t` or something similar) or you will need a multi-precision package such as GMP.

Comment: Isn't it safe to assume that a compiler that provides `__int128` also provides `int128_t`?

Comment: Whether `__int128` is available or not depends on your system. What environment do you program for?  If it is available, it is just an ordinary type, like `int` or `long int`.

Comment: @AswinRaghavan: Did this answer help you?

Comment: @user3528438: I'm afraid it's not.  I'm using gcc with the glibc on linux, `__int128_t` is available and functional, but `int128_t` is not and `intmax_t` has 64 bits.  The availability of `int128_t` would have wide ranging consequences for the C library and the compiler because `intmax_t` would then be required to have at least 128 bits, the preprocessing arithmetic would be done in 128 bits, etc.