# Is a 128 bit int written or loaded in two instructions in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety, int128

I know that there exists a `int128_t` type in C and C++.

If I have two threads one that is reading from a memory location containing this 128 bit integer and another that is writting to it.

Is there a chance that this value will be written as two 64 bit integer writes or will it be one 128 bit integer write?

Comment: That type is not guaranteed to be defined on all implementations, and how a compiler generates assembly depends on the compiler, platform and compilation flags/options. There is no portable answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't there int128\_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638723/why-isnt-there-int128-t)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about.   Use a proper synchronization technique and you should be fine.

Comment: No, you do not know this, because it does not exist in C/C++.

Comment: If you are worried about race conditions (will the reader be reading while the writer is writing) then you are correct to do so.  Tools for preventing race conditions are dependent on the language and OS, but some common ones are mutexes, critical sections, and signals. Mutexes are good when you want to make sure you're the only one doing something.

Comment: Depends on the compiler's translation and the capabilities of the processor.  If the processor can perform 128-bit transfers between memory and registers, the compiler will emit to do that.  Otherwise, the compiler will emit enough instructions to transfer 128-bits.  Anything from 16 8-bit transfers, block transfers or using DMA.  This is a platform (implementation) issue, so there is nothing in the C or C++ standard specifically about how to implement.

Comment: BTW, whether the 128 bits are read/written in a single instruction is immaterial to the read/write's atomicity. On AArch64 there are "load/store pair" instructions that transfer (up to) 128 bits from/to general registers in a single instruction, but the transfer is considered as two single-copy atomic transfers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support is discussed in other answers.  I'll discuss implementation issues.

Usually when reading from memory, the compiler will emit processor instructions to fetch the data from memory into a register.  This may be atomic depending on how the databus is set up between the processor and the memory.

If your processor supports 128-bit transfers and the memory supports 128-bit data bus, this could be a single fetch (or write).

If your processor supports 128-bit {register} transfers, but the data bus is smaller, the processor will perform enough fetches to transfer the data from memory.  This may or may not be atomic, depending on your definition of atomic (it's one processor instruction, but may require more than one fetch).

For processors that don't support 128-bit register transfers, the compiler will emit enough instructions to read the memory into register(s).  This is for register to memory or memory to register transfers.

For memory to memory transfers (e.g. variable assignments), the compiler may choose to use block reading and writing (if your processor has support for block reading and writing).  Some processors support SIMD, others may have block transfer instructions.  For example, the ARM has LDM (load multiple) and STM (store multiple) instructions for loading many registers from memory and storing many registers to memory.  Another method of block reading and writing is to use a DMA device (if present).  The DMA can transfer data while the processor executes other instructions.  However, the overhead to use the DMA may require more instructions than using 16 8-byte (byte) transfers.

In summary, compilers are not required to support `int128_t`.  If they do support it, there are various methods to transfer the data, depending on the processor and platform hardware support.  View the assembly language to see the instructions emitted by the compiler to support `int128_t`.

Comment: A better example might be AArch64 `ldp` / `stp` (load pair / store pair), since real compilers like GCC and Clang only implement `__int128` on 64-bit ISAs.  `ldp`/`stp` are even guaranteed atomic in ARMv8.4 for aligned data, including for a 16-byte pair of 8-byte halves, so `atomic<__int128>` can cheaply be lock-free on recent AArch64, earlier it requires an LL/SC retry loop that stores back the same value to be sure of atomicity (like on x86 without taking advantage of AVX's guarantee).  https://godbolt.org/z/14ovnWc8K shows Clang using `ldp` to deref an `__int128 *` or an `atomic<__int128>*`

Comment: The question was asking about atomicity.  The relevant bus is the path between L1d cache and load execution units, and commit from store buffer to L1d.  And the protocol for transferring cache lines between cores; that can introduce tearing, e.g. at 8-byte boundaries between sockets in AMD K10, but within a socket 16-byte SSE loads/stores were atomic if aligned.  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056) / [SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7647825)

Answer (score 5):

Neither C nor C++ are required to have an `int128_t` type, although if a compiler does support that type then it *must* be a `signed` 2's complement 128 bit integral type. But atomicity is not a requirement.

The behaviour on reading and writing to *any* type simultaneously that is not atomic is *undefined*.

In C++, if you could use `std::atomic<int128_t>` and, if your platform *does* have an atomic `int128_t` then that will be little more than a `typedef`.

Otherwise, and in C, your compiler *might* have an atomic 128 bit integral type. If not then you could roll your own version using inline assembly.

Comment: There is no `int128_t` in C++.

Comment: @SergeyA: Good point, although if they *do* have such a type then it needs to be a 128 bit 2's complement `signed`.

Comment: I keep running into this issue where I need to write to this value maybe 0.1% of the execution time. But reads to this value happen about 10% of execution time. Using a most thread syncs are expensive. I was hoping to find a way around this cost but it looks like it will have to be payed. Thanks

Comment: @MarcusKarpoff - consider using something like an assembly bus lock. That will be an order of magnitude faster than a mutex, and probably no more expensive than a pipeline dump.

Answer (score 3):

First off, there is **no** `int128_t` type in C++. The largest standard type is `int64_t`.

Second off, some platforms provide a 128-bit integer type as an extension. For example, gcc/clang/icc support `__int128` type.

To correctly use this type in multithreading scenarios, one has (as with any other type!) either protect the access with appropriate synchronization constructs, or use `std::atomic<__int128>`. Platforms which support `__int128`, usually support atomic version of it as well.

And just to satisfy your curiosity, I do not know any common hardware currently in use which could support 128 bit integers natively.

Comment: some platforms and VISs do support 128-bit pointers at least for future compatibily. underlying cpus are 64bit.  that explaiins existence of such in nearly all major compilers (intel, pgi, lahey  supported under different names)

Comment: _there is no int128_t type in C++_: This is **not true**.  The Standard merely refers the fixed-size integer types to the C standard. which defines what `int`N`_t` should be for all _N_.  Although various versions of the C standard _mention_ 
 `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, and `int64_t` it also labels them as **optional**.  A platform with a 48- or 96-bit word would have `int48_t` and `int96_t` but not `int64_t`.   So `int128_t` (or `int1024_t` for that matter)  is as much a part of the Standard as is `int64_t`.   Not only that, the C+23 Draft Standard explicitly spells all of this out.

Comment: Of course, `uint_least64_t` is required and has to be at least 64 bits.